# Default Location of MSBuild on Azure DevOps Windows Agents

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines

I'm working on setting up a pipeline in Azure DevOps that involves using MSBuild on Windows agents. However, I'm not sure about the default location where MSBuild is installed on Azure DevOps Windows agents. I've looked through the documentation, but I couldn't find clear information about this.

Could someone provide me with insights about the default location of MSBuild on Azure DevOps Windows agents? This would help me configure my pipeline correctly.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: What is the specific issue you're having? MSBuild is part of the `PATH` environment variable and shouldn't need to be fully qualified.

Comment: @DanielMann You are not right, MSBuild task requires full path to MsBuild.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSBuild is installed alongside Visual Studio in Windows based agents. You will find it here `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe`.

Comment: Could you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful?

Comment: Absolutely! Your response was really helpful, and I've just upvoted it. Thanks for taking the time to assist me with my question!